# A sequence of more than one item is not allowed as the first operand of 'ne' ("72686200", "72686200")

Tags: xpath, xslt

I am trying to replace the 13th value on the 2nd string with what I have on 1st string.

726862 should be replaced with 72686200. This value is from an other element. Is there a way I can do this with a variable and should replace when we have multiple strings.

I keep getting -  A sequence of more than one item is not allowed as the first operand of 'ne' ("72686200", "72686200")
...done

Comment: What kind of value do you expect for e.g. `CurrentRateClass` and `PreviousRateClass`? Your XPath select seems to have a sequence of two or more as you select both the result of tokenize plus a constant string in `/*:Transaction/*:Ratings/*:Rating[*:Premiums/*:Premium[*:Category/@*:SourceKey='PRP']/*:Amount !=0]/tokenize(@*:SourceKey,'\|')[13],'72686200'`.

Comment: @RaoE Please do not post code in comments - edit your question and provide a way to reproduce the problem.

Comment: That still does not allow us to reproduce the problem - see [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this example can help you:

Input:

```
<root>
    <source>1|22|333|4444|55555|666666|7777777</source>   
    <target>A|BB|CCC|DDDD|EEEEE|FFFFFF|GGGGGGG</target>   
</root>
```

XSLT (version 2.0):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/root"> 
    <result> 
        <xsl:variable name="tgt" select="tokenize(target, '\|')" />
        <xsl:value-of select="$tgt[position() lt 5], tokenize(source, '\|')[5], $tgt[position() gt 5]" separator="|"/>
    </result> 
</xsl:template> 

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Result:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<result>A|BB|CCC|DDDD|55555|FFFFFF|GGGGGGG</result>
```

Here we replaced the 5th token of the second string with the 5th token of the first one.

Comment: @RaoE Sorry, but I cannot help you any further without a reproducible example (including your input), as others have already requested. And please stop posting code in comments (also already requested).

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code:

```
<xsl:template name="CheckRateClassChange" match="*:template[@*:name='CheckRateClassChange']">
  <xsl:if test="$Activity/*:Transaction/...">
     <xsl:for-each select="$Activity/*:Transaction/...">
        <xsl:variable name="CurrentRateClass"
                      select="/*:Transaction/*:Ratings/..."/>
        <xsl:variable name="PreviousRateClass"
                      select="$LastSnapshot/*:Transaction/..."/>
        <xsl:if test="$CurrentRateClass ne $PreviousRateClass">
```

Experienced users would generally add an "as" clause to the variables to declare their expected type; that would simply give you an earlier and slightly more focussed explanation of what is wrong.

You haven't supplied any justification for believing that either of these complex path expressions should return a single value, so the evidence in front of us says that they don't. If you believe that they should return singletons, then you need to show us the source document to justify this belief.

An online XPath visualiser such as the one in Oxygen might help you to assess what your XPath expressions are actually returning.